# How to create a CLI wrapper for a C++ library?

Tags: c#, c++, command-line-interface

I have the header files(***.hpp**) and source files(***.cpp**) to a library. I built the library from source using CMake, then used Visual Studio to build it, which created a **.lib** file. To create a CLI wrapper, I need a header file that enumerates all the methods in the library in it, and a source file that creates proxy functions and defines their behavior.

The tutorials on the internet describe manually creating proxy functions and defining the headers, but the library has several hundred functions in source and header files, so I am looking for an easier way to create a CLI wrapper.

The tutorials I followed were:

1. https://drthitirat.wordpress.com/2013/06/03/use-c-codes-in-a-c-project-wrapping-native-c-with-a-managed-clr-wrapper/
2. https://dominoc925.blogspot.com/2016/08/use-cmake-to-help-build-and-use-windows.html

I wish to use these C++ functions in C#.

Comment: Not sure if it is right to the point but there is this command line parser https://github.com/bfgroup/Lyra that you could use. Put in in your main.cpp and make it call your library functions with the arguments provided by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Swig](http://swig.org) library. It provides a comprehensive range of options to generate wrappers for C#, Java, Python, Tcl and many other popular languages. It is easy to use, and the documentation provided is extremely clear and helpful.